# How can I open a modal in VueJS using bootstrap?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to open a modal in my Vue Template using boostrap. but whenever I try using jquery on it, modal is not appearing.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app_religion">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Open</button> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  @click="showModal()">
      Open
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    methods: {
        showModal() {
          console.log("test")
          $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I am really new in using Vue, can anyone guide me on how to solve my problem. I am really lost on trying to figure it out.

Comment: what error are you getting on the console?

Comment: Nothing sir. there is error appearing in my console.

Comment: I am not sure. did you run "npm run watch" or "npm run dev" after change on the component?

Comment: yes. the modal is appearing if i am not using the jquery function. but whenever i am trying to use the modal('show') in jquery, modal is not appearing but when i inspect element it, the modal class has a show on its class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily implemented through plain js

Start by assigning a unique id to your modal

`<div class="modal fade" id="uniqueId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uniqueIdlLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

import Modal from bootstrap

`import { Modal } from "bootstrap";`

Declare a variable that will serve as your proxy to your modal, declared as `uniqueModal` below, Assign the variable the DOM element retrieved by `uniqueId`, use the inbuilt functions provided by bootstrap to manipulate the modal. [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript)

```
export default {
    name:"randomName",
     data(){
     return {uniqueModal:null}
    },
    methods:
    {
     showUniqueModal() {
      this.uniqueModal = new Modal(document.getElementById("uniqueId"),{ keyboard: false });
      this.uniqueModal.show();
      },
     closeUniqueModal() {
      this.uniqueModal.hide();
     },
    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why trying to do it with jQuery when you can make it with vue ?

use v-if or v-show on your modal (check the difference between the two and take the one who fits better the result you want)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Didn't tested it, i wrote it on the fly, but something like this should work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  @click="showModal">
      Open
    </button>
    <div class="modal" v-if="modalOpen">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        modalOpen: false
      }
    },
    
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.modalOpen = true;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```